# Refactoring Nested If's

Tags: c#, algorithm

Say you have 5 functions that return boolean values and depending on the values returned by the functions you need to return a value. For example

you have functions `f1, f2, f3, f4, f5` that each take no parameters and return true or false. This gives you 2^5 possibilities and for each one you need to return a unique number so if

```
f1() = true, f2() = true, f3() = true, f4() = true, f5() = true return 1

f1() = true, f2() = true, f3() = true, f4() = true, f5() = false return 2

f1() = true, f2() = true, f3() = true, f4() = false, f5() = false return 3
..
..
```

besides using a huge number of nested if's whats a clean way of doing this?

Additional Details:

This is a simplification of a problem I'm working on. Based off a number of function that work like above I'm trying to determine the status of an order form that is represented by an enumeration. For example I am doing: IfCertainCondition1() and IfCertainCondition2() then OrderFormStatus.New, IfCertainCondition1() and NOT IfCertainCondiction2() then OrderFormStatus.SomethingElse. Doing this works but as there are a large number of Conditions it makes for very heavy nested if's

Comment: With more detail someone could probably help you rethink that design.  I've never encounter such a situation in real life or anything similar.

Comment: I agree. You should try to rethink your logic and see if there is a better way to accomplish what it is you're trying to do

Comment: @pwny: Such a thing isn't so uncommon, although we often express it in different ways. Imagine a program that uses five (or more) interrelated conditions to evaluate risk. You can't say that condition 1 increases your risk by X, because its effect depends on whether condition 2 or condition 3 is also true.  So you create a mapping table that returns the pre-calculated risk values based on the true/false values of all the conditions. There are many ways to implement such a thing, this being one of them.

Comment: I understand your premise and it makes a lot of sense.  However, this *feels* like a debatable decision in this case; a decision people here might be able to help improve provided they get more details.  I meant to say I never encountered a situation where a bunch of nested if statements was the unique or even most graceful solution.  (Although the combination into an integer approach is rather interesting and I did not think about that in the first place)

Answer (score 7):

You could combine them into a single integer, with each bit in the integer representing the bool return from one method.

```
bool f1, f2, f3, f4, f5;
int combined = f1 ? 0x01 : 0 | f2 ? 0x02 : 0 | f3 ? 0x04 : 0 | f4 ? 0x08 : 0 | f5 ? 0x10 : 0;
return combined;
// or 
int conversionTable[32] = { ... };
return conversionTable[combined];
```

Comment: I think f5 should return 0x16 tho. 0x10 is going to set your 0x02 and 0x08 bits

Comment: @Nicklamort: No, f5 should return 0x10 (16 decimal).

Comment: This is the kind of answer I was thinking of when I first read the question. Nice job.

Answer (score 4):

```
unsigned int foo =   ( f1() ? 1 : 0 ) 
                   | ( ( f2() ? 1 : 0 ) << 1 )
                   | ( ( f3() ? 1 : 0 ) << 2 )
                   | ( ( f4() ? 1 : 0 ) << 3 )
                   | ( ( f5() ? 1 : 0 ) << 4 );

switch ( foo ) {
    case 0:
        // Whatever you do if they're all false
        break;
    case 1:
        // Blah blah blah
        break;
    // ... 23 more cases ... 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In .NET, the `Boolean` type holds values `True` (1) or `False` (0).  You can exploit that and write your code without any conditionals at all:

```
int x = (int)f1();
x |= ((int)f2()) << 1;
x |= ((int)f3()) << 2;
x |= ((int)f4()) << 3;
x |= ((int)f5()) << 4;
```

You could potentially structure the above code so that it returns the values you want without resorting to a lookup table that maps the computed `x` value to the actual value you want to return.

Another way to do it would be to create an array of functions:

```
Func<bool>[] funcs = new Func<bool>[] { f1, f2, f3, f4, f5 };
int x = 0;
foreach (var f in funcs)
{
    x = (x << 1) | (int)f();
}
```

Or, if you don't want to depend on `Boolean` always being 0 or 1:

```
foreach (var f in funcs)
{
    x <<= 1;
    if (f())
        x |= 1;
}
```

Added later, after your additional details:

You say that you're using an enum.  I assume you have values 0 through 31 (or perhaps 1 through 32), something like:

```
public enum OrderFormStatus
{
    New = 1,
    SomethingElse = 2,
    // ... etc
}
```

Then you can use the code above to generate your value and just cast it to the enum type.  That is, after computing `x`, write:

```
OrderFormStatus ofs = (OrderFormStatus)x;
```

Or, if your values are 1..32 rather than 0..31:

```
OrderFormStatus ofs = (OrderFormStatus)(x+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
int x = 0;
if (f1()) x+=16;
if (f2()) x+=8;
if (f3()) x+=4;
if (f4()) x+=2;
if (f5()) x+=1;
return x;
```

From the result you can check remainders and know exactly which functions returned true;